# notification action center does not work

Tags: notifications

My action center does not work on scrolling down from the upper part of the screen , on my windows phone 8.1

I tried reseting the phone but it didn't help.

Do you have a solution?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Can you confirm the OS version (from **settings** > **about** > **[more information]**)?

Answer (score -1):

Try to restore or fix it using [Windows Phone Recovery Tools](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/mobile/support/faq/?action=singleTopic&topic=FA142987). It works like charm.